# fetching only mobile section record (not from iphone, home label etc) from addressbook?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, ios4

How do I fetch only mobile section record from **addressbook** in ios?

I want to add only one record to my array that is fetched from **mobile section record**.

How do I do that. I am getting all the phone property records. but I need to get only mobile section record.

```
NSArray *allPeople = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(myAddressBook);
NSLog(@"allpeople%@", allPeople);

for (id record in allPeople) {
    CFTypeRef phoneProperty = ABRecordCopyValue((ABRecordRef)record, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    NSArray *phones = (NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(phoneProperty);

    NSLog(@"phones %@",phones);

    CFRelease(phoneProperty);
    NSMutableDictionary *newRecord = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSMutableString *newPhone = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    for (NSString *phone in phones) {
        if(![newPhone isEqualToString:@""])
            [newPhone appendString:@", "];
        [newPhone appendString:phone];
    }
```

Comment: you want to fetch mobile number from address book ?

Comment: @popeye yeah only mobile number from adressbook

Comment: then why don't you want to use (abPerson,kabpersonphonemobilelabel) ?

Comment: @popeye CFTypeRef phoneProperty = ABRecordCopyValue((ABRecordRef)record, kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel); is this right?

Comment: have you seen my answer ? please check whether working for you or not ?

Comment: @popeye will check and let you know thanks for sharing:)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this..

```
ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(abPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    if (phoneNumbers) {
        CFIndex numberOfPhoneNumbers = ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers);
        for (CFIndex i = 0; i < numberOfPhoneNumbers; i++) {
            NSString *phone = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, i);
            CFStringRef label = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phoneNumbers, i);
            if (label) {
                if (CFEqual(label, kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel)) {
                    primaryPhoneText.text = phone;
                } else {
                }
                CFRelease(label);
                [allPhones addObject:phone]; // allPhones is an array here.
            }
        }
        CFRelease(phoneNumbers);
    }
```

Hope this will help you out..

Enjoy coding..